# Data structure and type of file to use communicate between 2 processes written in Python and C

Tags: python, c

Details:

1. I have source code for both the process.
2. They communicate over sockets using TCP.
3. Message size varies from 10bytes to 100KB to 1MB.
4. Both the process run on the same machine hence latency is ~0.
5. Python process is the parent and C is the child.
6. Both the process communicate with each other. i.e Duplex connection.
7. Source code of C is huge. Won't be easy to wrap it around python. (not too keen to do that as well since C developers might need to learn Python)
8. Python process is a web app written in Django.
9. Common place to have the message declarations so when a new field in the message is added, it should be simple to propogate the change to both the process.

Questions:

1. A common file which contains the format of the messages. What should be the type of the file?
2. What should be the type of the data structure?

Is it a good idea to use struct in header file and have python parse it?
Any better way?

Comment: [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) and [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) are two common data-exchange formats, both are very extensible where you can add new fields when needed, and can easily check for existence of these fields.

Answer (score 1):

you should go for XML-RPC the python APIs are given here

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XML-RPC-HOWTO/xmlrpc-howto-python.html

and the C API are given here

http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/example-code.php

it will become easy to debug also if XML or JSON RPC is used.